# MongoDB: Set and get Sub Document Schema

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongoose and I have users collection shown below, but I now want to allow the user to save a number of articles, an article has a title, subtitle, and body, One user can have many articles.

How can I restructure the users collection to allow the articles to be added

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    fullName: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I'm using the below to set new data to the user's collection, how do I adapt it to allow me to set and get the new articles detailed above?

```
const confirmed = await userModel
   .findOneAndUpdate(
      { email },
        {
         $set: { password },
        }
      )
      .exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option `strict: false` and add(save) new fields to your schema.

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    fullName: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    strict: false,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Here is the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)